# Matrix with integer random rows

Tags: r, matrix, random, integer

The command

```
 matrix(sample.int(12, 9*12, TRUE), 9, 12)
```

generates an integer random matrix (9 rows and 12 columns) with integer values from 1 to 12. I wonder if there is a version of this code that generates a matrix whose rows are integer random rows with value from 1 to 12 (without repetition). I was able to find a "trivial" answer to this question; with

```
matrix(sample.int(m, 1*12), 9, 12, byrow=TRUE)
```

I obtain a matrix of this kind, but the rows are all equal to each other (this is the same row repeated 9 times).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `replicate` function (which repeats an operation like `sample(12)` a specified number of times) returns a matrix whose column major orientation can be flipped to your desired row orientation with `t`:

```
t( replicate(9, {sample(12)} ) )
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12]
 [1,]    9   11    5    3    4    6    2    8   10    12     7     1
 [2,]    4    5   12    6    8    2    9    1   11    10     7     3
 [3,]    9    8   10   12    2    6    3    7    4     1    11     5
 [4,]    4    9    1    2    6   11    8    5    7     3    12    10
 [5,]    1    2    4    5   11    6    3    8   10     9    12     7
 [6,]    4    8   10   12    5    9    2    7   11     1     3     6
 [7,]    5    7    8    4    1    6   10   11    2     3    12     9
 [8,]    2    4   10    1   12    5    7    6   11     3     8     9
 [9,]    2    7    9   11    8    1   12   10    6     5     3     4
```

The `replicate` function is used in a lot of simulation code.